# Python: Is their a way to perform anytree functionality into networkx?

Tags: python, tree, subtree

I'm searching some networkx functionality for general tree generation like that:

```
from anytree import Node, RenderTree, AsciiStyle, PreOrderIter
f = Node("f")
b = Node("b", parent=f)
a = Node("a", parent=b)
d = Node("d", parent=b)
c = Node("c", parent=d)
e = Node("e", parent=d)
g = Node("g", parent=f)
i = Node("i", parent=g)
h = Node("h", parent=i)
print(RenderTree(f, style=AsciiStyle()).by_attr())

print([node.name for node in PreOrderIter(f)])
```

output:

```
f
|-- b
|   |-- a
|   +-- d
|       |-- c
|       +-- e
+-- g
    +-- i
        +-- h
['f', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'e', 'g', 'i', 'h']
```

so I can simply find subnotes or subtrees of some tree node?